# How do I know if I've unlocked a prestige badge?

Tags: spiral-knights

Prestige badges were added to Spiral Knights today, given out at various prestige milestones. The first badge is awarded at 5,000 prestige.

However, I'm already over 5,000 prestige and mousing over any mention of prestige says my next badge is at 5,000...

How can I tell if I've unlocked this badge?

Comment: It's probably just not rewarded retroactively.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think so too, but I'd like some way to know if I've got it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have earned it, the proper symbol is displayed next to your name.

Note the symbol for the first level:

[image]

And here it is again:

[image]

As for the process of actually having it bestowed, there's....absolutely nothing.  Just an icon appears by your name.

Answer (score 1):

That's all you get. The symbol next to your name is considered to be **an honor** by most. You do not get any *extra* award. No message, no prize, just a *nice looking symbol* next to your name.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Please do not ask peoples to add you as friend in your answers. We are not a discussion forum, and you should only answer the question at hands. See the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: When I asked this, I didn't even know I got that symbol.  :3  Now, I'm almost to 45k! :D